# Allow and deny notifications directly from a webpage in Safari

Tags: safari

How can I allow and deny notifications for a site directly from the webpage?
Going into Settings - Websites - Notifications and looking for the site is cumbersome.
The menu under Safari - Settings for [website] doesn't allow editing notification permissions.

[image]